# Serialize and Deserialize multiple type of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

We have 2 (or more) classes:

```
class numOne
{
     string name;
     int age;
}
class numTwo
{
     Bitmap pImage;
}
```

And I have an ArrayList that contains instances of these classes:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
numOne n1 = new numOne(){ name="sth", age =18 };
numTwo n2 = new numTwo(){ pImage = new Bitmap("FileAddress") };
list.Add(n1);
list.Add(n2);
```

I know when we have A type of class. How can I serialize and deserialize the objects (Like a List<>) with `BinaryFormatter`?
I don't know how I can use this operation for ArrayLists and other complex objects like this.

Comment: With `DataContractSerializer` there's an [overload of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx) that takes `IEnumerable<Type>` of known types in the list. You could do this to let it take any type that the array list has: `new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), list.Select(x => x.GetType()))`.

Comment: As an aside, why are you mixing types in a list? That's a code smell, to me. Unless they extend from a common base class, in which case you could use a `List<BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work for you ?

```
 [Serializable]
        class numOne
        {
            public string name;
            public int age;
        }
        [Serializable]
        class numTwo
        {
            public string rg;
        }
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
//Serialization
            using (var fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create))
            {
                var listToBeSerialized = new ArrayList(){                
                new numOne() { name = "sth", age = 18 },
                new numTwo() { rg = "FileAddress" }
            };
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fs, listToBeSerialized);
            }

//Deserialization
            using (var fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open))
            {
                var deserializedList = (ArrayList)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
```

For the Bitmap class , you have to check if it's serializable.

Comment: I checked and your solution is CORRECT ;-) Thank you